# PowerShell PackageManagement not found

Tags: windows, powershell, wmf

I'm trying to avoid having to restore my PC and get it back to where I was. I was recently going to delete a folder using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, but without paying too close attention I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on the modules folder in C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Modules.

I had re-imported PowerShellGet, PackageManagement, as well as Pester.

I thought I was in the clear but I keep running into issues, I have to always Re-Import PowershellGet. Then I get another error.

> Get-PSRepository : The term 'PackageManagement\Get-PackageSource' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file.

Even after doing `Import-PackageManagement` I still get that error.

If I do `(Get-Module -List Available -Name PackageManagement).Exportedcmdlets` it shows that `Get-PackageSource` is there.

I'm really not sure what I need to do to fix this.

I have uninstalled and reintalled WMF 5.1, but the issue persists.

I am running Windows 8.1

Comment: `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Refresh`

Comment: That doesn't seem to help either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with PackageManagement, 1.1.4.0. I deleted that reimported PackageManagement based on what i read here. https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/195

It seems to be working now.

Comment: Nice one. That's a long thread - consider adding some detail to the answer about how you diagnosed and resolved it, to help anyone who has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

[PowerShell is an open source project](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/09/29/powershellget-and-packagemanagement-in-powershell-gallery-and-github/). You can download the modules from github. That link also describes how to get from PowerShell Gallery, which may work for you.

- [Main PowerShell repo](https://github.com/powershell)
- [PackageManagement (aka Oneget)](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget)

Comment: I should have specified. i got the powershell managament from Powershell Gallery and the PowershellGet from the github repo. I have them, i have to constantly import the and still they say they do not exist.